# IRC USER message makes no sense to me

Tags: irc

First, please tell me if I'm not allowed to ask about this protocol here... It just seemed like the best place. Sorry if I'm wrong.

So according to wikipedia the USER message goes like the following:

```
USER username hostname servername :realname
```

What's the difference between hostname and servername? Thanks.

Comment: The question is off-topic - you should only ask programming related questions here.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a standards reference. Try [RFC 1459](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt).

Comment: Okay, sorry! Do I need to remove it? Also @Greg, it appeared the same in the RFC as it was on wikipedia.

Comment: If enough users vote to migrate it to http://superuser.com it will move there automatically.

Comment: Can I move it myself? I hate to be annoying. :\ But I'm not sure how...

Comment: IMO, it's a programming question.  The OP is implementing the protocol.  A superuser shouldn't need to know this level of detail, only a coder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RFC 1459](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt) states in section 4.1.3:

> Note that hostname and servername are normally ignored by the IRC server when the USER command comes from a directly connected client (for security reasons), but they are used in server to server communication.

Answer (score 4):

USER command from RFC1459 is modified in RFC2812 which moots your question slightly.

Comment: It bugs me though that [RFC2812](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812) is only informational and doesn't define a standard, even though it obviously conflicts with the old [RFC1459](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459.html). So which to trust? RFC2812 might be newer, but it specifically states it's not a standard.

Comment: @Maarten RFC2812 was written by the IRCnet alone, most IRCds ignore that RFC. `!` are not implemented on most servers, and most clients can't handle them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The "hostname" is that of the *client*.

Comment: For privacy reasons, you should not expose the client hostname. Use something else. Some clients use a hardcoded `-`, other use the username again, and others send `localhost`. It does not matter what you send.